# Alignment shows some red, car still pulling right

Tags: alignment

[image]

I know this has been asked but I wanted to see if there is anything here that is alarming. I still have a noticeable pull to the right if not worse than when I took the car in. Thank you in advance for any input

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Check your tire pressure; I would imagine the shop that had that fancy alignment printout would have done that, but you never know....

Answer (score 1):

The front end looks about dead on as it's going to get. The back end would not bother me as it is out of "standard" by about .1° in the right rear camber, which is not a lot. Besides, on most cars, there's nothing you can do for the back end besides changing parts. If it's pulling still, I'd suggest there's a mechanical issue with the car. It might be a dragging brake caliper or something else in the steering department.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Could a tire rotation eliminate any mechanical issues?

Comment: @Jrodriguez209 - No, an alignment will not fix it. When I said a "mechanical issue", I mean something physically wrong with the vehicle which is causing the pull.

Comment: A tire rotation is a good idea. Sometimes internal tire wear can cause a pull. Try switching the front tires. I've seen this work on multiple occasions.

Comment: @Jupiter - Good point and thanks for the add.